# How to do I make an ajax call on submit and also make sure that the html5 validation also happen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to do I make an ajax call on submit and also make sure that the html5 validation also happen

```
<form action="someurl" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
  <input type="text" id="name" required placeholder="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
  <input type="text" id="description" required placeholder="Description">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Category</button>
</form>
```

I know how to make an ajax call. I just want to know how should be handling the submit button so that the validations take place and also the ajax function

Like I don't which jquery method to use out here. I displaying these forms in twitter bootstrap modal.

I got a reference material of what I actually trying to do --- http://albertbori.com/ajax-form-validation-with-html5 -- But I did the same thing and Still it didn't work

Comment: if it does not work, u sure ur browser supports html5?

Comment: It does support html5. Its the latest version of Chromium Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //code goes here
});
```

which on submission it runs this function which would include your validation and ajax call

Comment: My browser tab is getting redirected to another page and there i can see my json response

Comment: the comment out `e.preventDefault();` unless I'm not understanding your response to "it doesn't work"

Comment: i tried it both ways . It didn't work. The issue is that when I am actually using the debugger in my browser. It doesn't even enter the function block. It just redirects and displays the json response

Comment: have you tried adding something like `console.log('submit');` into the function. Also do you have jquery added to your code?

Comment: I have jquery added to my code and also I have tried console.log('submit')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28291/discussion-between-class-and-c-j)

Comment: the issue was something else. SOmething really interesting

Answer (score 2):

as base you can use `inputElement.checkValidity()`
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/WebForms/checkValidity

maybe you're looking for this

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             ...
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
```

Comment: theres an automated way of doing it and I don't want to do it manually. I have actually seen it somewhere I just can't remember it Thanks anyways

Comment: u can use it with form, like $('form').checkValidity()